# Mutable optional OutputPin

Tags: rust

I'm stuck with ownership; I but can't make the `Option<OutputPin>` in my function usable. How should it be?

```
struct Chip {
    wake_pin: Option<OutputPin>,
}

impl Chip {
    pub fn new(wake_pin: Option<Pin>) -> Chip {
        Chip {
            wake_pin: wake_pin.map(|pin| pin.into_output()),
        }
    }

    pub fn awake(&self) {
        // Fails
        if let Some(pin) = self.wake_pin {
            pin.set_low();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let wake_pin = Gpio::new()
        .expect("Can not init gpio")
        .get(255)
        .expect("Could not attach to wake pin");

    let chip = Chip::new(Some(wake_pin));
}
```

I am using the rppal crate and the compiler fails in the `if let Some` area. I tried to borrow `wake_pin`, get the `Option` as a reference and some other things but I don't understand the ownership rules completely.

Comment: Please share the actual error. Also, what is OutputPin and which crates/use lines are needed to compile your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've duplicated your set up. If something isn't right, please **edit** your question with the relevant details.

src/main.rs:

```
use rppal::gpio::{Gpio, OutputPin, Pin};

struct Chip {
    wake_pin: Option<OutputPin>,
}

impl Chip {
    pub fn new(wake_pin: Option<Pin>) -> Chip {
        Chip {
            wake_pin: wake_pin.map(|pin| pin.into_output()),
        }
    }

    pub fn awake(&self) {
        // Fails
        if let Some(pin) = self.wake_pin {
            pin.set_low();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let wake_pin = Gpio::new()
        .expect("Can not init gpio")
        .get(255)
        .expect("Could not attach to wake pin");

    let chip = Chip::new(Some(wake_pin));
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rppal = "0.11.3"
```

Attempting to compile this (with `cargo check` or similar), we get a warning and two errors.

```
warning: unused variable: `chip`
  --> src/main.rs:28:9
   |
28 |     let chip = Chip::new(Some(wake_pin));
   |         ^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_chip`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.wake_pin.0` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:16:28
   |
16 |         if let Some(pin) = self.wake_pin {
   |                     ---    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.wake_pin`
   |                     |
   |                     data moved here
   |                     move occurs because `pin` has type `rppal::gpio::pin::OutputPin`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `pin` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
16 |         if let Some(pin) = self.wake_pin {
   |                     --- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut pin`
17 |             pin.set_low();
   |             ^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0507, E0596.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: Could not compile `tmp`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Since you're presumably going to use `chip` later, we can silence the warning by temporarily renaming it to `_chip`.

`let _chip = Chip::new(Some(wake_pin));`

The first error tells us that we can't move the pin out of `self` since we're only borrowing `self`. It would be rather rude to invalidate the data behind self if we're only borrowing it. However, the compiler is telling us a solution. `` help: consider borrowing here: `&self.wake_pin` ``

It ends up not quite being right, but it's the right direction.

```
if let Some(pin) = &self.wake_pin {
    pin.set_low();
}
```

Now instead of `pin` having type `OutputPin` (an owned value), it has type `&OutputPin` (a borrowed value).

We still get the second error though (with a slightly different phrasing). The point is that `pin.set_low()` requires `pin` to be a mutable reference. Right now, we're taking `self` as an immutable reference (`pub fn awake(&self)`). If we're going to mutate `self` or any of its fields, we need to take it mutably. This also means we need to make sure `pin` is borrowed mutably.

```
pub fn awake(&mut self) {
    if let Some(pin) = &mut self.wake_pin {
        pin.set_low();
    }
}
```